# Java -version is not showing any version or error

Tags: java, java-8

I have added java path in system variables, I tried to check java version by `java -version`
but I am not getting any error or any version :
[image]

Path Variables:

[image]

why the java -version command is not giving any result

Comment: Have you tried moving the java path a bit further up? Also your PATH variable looks a bit messed up. It is missing some standard windows paths.

Comment: @McPringle Chances are that OP doesn't speak German. Please translate your comment in English.

Comment: You should move jdk environment variable to first. Another program call 'java' may interact with your java/jdk

Comment: Sorry, switching languages too many times...

Are you really sure you still want to use Java 8? Currently, Java 17 is the most recent version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I observed my Environment Variables , there are some of the paths added for Oracle :

> i.e. C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

I have removed this paths as it was not in use. And it started showing me correct versions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You have to restart your CMD window after changing the Environment variable.
Please do so and retest.

If it's still not working, check in CMD if Java is on the PATH:

```
echo %PATH%
```

If it's on the PATH, then check if the path is actually correct:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java" -version
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you restarted your command windows since you added your environment variable ? They are loaded when the window is created and not updated after this.

Besides, what happens if you set manually your environment variable with `set JAVA_HOME=<your_path>` ? Does the java -version print any output ? You need to try that.