# Java does not print anything despite being listed on the PATH

Tags: java, installation, path, console, bin

As the title suggests, I am having trouble running any java files from my command line/text editors. While I am able to run and test things on VSCode, anything outside of that does not work. My `JAVA_HOME` is set up within my System variables as the correct path (`D:\Coding\Java\jdk-18`)  along with adding the bin path (`D:\Coding\Java\jdk-18\bin`) to the `PATH` variable. I assume java is on my machine as I do not receive any errors when I run `java -version` on my command line, however nothing prints.

EDIT: I'm on Windows 10 if that helps with anything

Comment: Are you sure that nothing prints? Or it prints an error within the command line?

Comment: Nothing prints, there is no error, and I don't know if things are actually "running" as stuff like class files aren't even created. [Here is an album of what it looks like](https://imgur.com/a/7qQIQ1u)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69218931/java-version-is-not-showing-any-version-or-error] does this answer your question?

Comment: can you please try java --version command with two dashes?

Comment: Your link actually helped me think of the answer! After thinking for a bit I realized that there might have been older parts of the `PATH` variable that took priority over my latest entry. Moving it up and removing anything that looked like it might override the java call worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there was an older portion of the `PATH` variable that was taking priority of the java name and caused the lack of printing. Moving up the `D:\Coding\Java\jdk-18\bin` while also deleting anything that looked like might override the java call was what worked for me.